# Rename a snapshot in Hyper-V WMI V2 from C#

Tags: rename, snapshot, hyper-v

I am trying to rename a Hyper-V snapshot (checkpoint) using root\virtualization\v2. None of the standard methods like ModifySystemSettings or ModifyVirtualSystem of Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService or Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService has been helpful so far.

Powershell Rename-VMSnapshot can do the job however I am not sure it is using WMI.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
//
// Rename last snapshot to desired name
//
using (ManagementBaseObject inParams = vmms.GetMethodParameters("ModifySystemSettings"))
{
    ManagementObject setting = null;

    ManagementObjectCollection settings = vm.GetRelated(
        "Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData",
        "Msvm_MostCurrentSnapshotInBranch",
        null,
        null,
        "Dependent",
        "Antecedent",
        false,
        null
        );

    foreach (ManagementObject instance in settings)
    {
        // Usually only one, but loop through to the end to get latest one

        if (setting != null)
        {
            if (string.Compare(
                    (string)instance["CreationTime"],
                    (string)setting["CreationTime"],
                    true) > 0
                )
            {
                // Get latest one since there could be duplicates
                setting = instance;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            setting = instance;
        }
    }

    setting["ElementName"] = snapshotName;

    inParams["SystemSettings"] = setting.GetText(TextFormat.WmiDtd20);

    using (ManagementBaseObject outParams = vmms.InvokeMethod("ModifySystemSettings", inParams, null))
    {
        // What this does is get Job managementObject and check JobState to be JobCompleted.
        this.ProcessSnapshotMethodResult(outParams, "rename");
    }
}
```

Comment: I created sub function as ProcessSnapshotMethodResult() to wait for the async call ModifySystemSettings to complete. It also checks the result of async call. It is similar to ValidateOutput mothod in common utilities introduced in MSDN here:[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850032(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: setting.GetText(TextFormat.WmiDtd20); -> do you know how to write this part of code in the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure with CimInstance instead of ManagementObject?